# Bitmap doesn't retain changes made in View's onSizeChanged method

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am creating a drawing application which allows users to draw using finger. For that I've implemented Canvas backed by a bitmap. I'm initializing canvas and bitmap by overriding `onSizeChanged` method and I'm also setting bitmap color to RED.

```
class DrawingView extends View{
    Canvas canvas;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        
        // setting the color to RED
        canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);
        // This prints correct color at position x and y.
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(bitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y)));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // This prints wrong color. Always print "0" (black)
                System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(bitmap.getPixel((int)x, (int)y)));
        }
}
```

But it seems that the color set in `onSizeChanged` method doesn't retain in the bitmap and when I print the bitmap color in `onTouchEvent` method, it always prints black color (0).

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Cannot repro - Always get 0xffff0000 for me.

Comment: @Darkman Even in onTouch?

Comment: Yes, both in `onSizeChanged()` and `onTouchEvent()`.

Comment: @Darkman Can you show me your onDraw method?

Comment: There was no `onDraw()`. Copy&pasted your exact code. Of course I had to set the initial `x` and `y` to zero.

Comment: One more thing. I didn't use `System.out.println()` but `Toast.makeText()` instead.

Comment: @Darkman Okay thanks man. I have so much code around other than these methods so there must be a bug in there as it's working correctly for you. Let me debug it.